# Performance in MYSQL when something != something

Tags: mysql, database, performance

This is more of a theoretical question about performance and speed of queries and how they work in a Relational Database.

Lets say I have a table with 100,000 rows, having a column called status.

10,000 have a status 'active', while 90,000 have status 'inactive'.

If I query using !='active'.  Am I then really only querying the active rows by default?  Or does it still have to 'scan' all the rows

What I mean is that will performance be affected depending on the amount of rows I have as inactive.

For instance....if I have 10,000,000 rows inactive, and 10,000 active.  Will the queries on the active rows take the same amount of time (wether I have 100,000 inactive, or 10,000,000 inactive), since Im 'discarding' the 10,000,000 inactive rows by the !='active' query.

Hopefully Im explaining myself properly.

Basically Im asking is if the active row count stays the same, does the query always take the same amount of time, since Im not really 'looking at' the inactives.

Comment: if your table becomes greater (read couple of milllons) you may want to read something about partitioning http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/partitioning.html . i advise to use list here because this has less overhead vs linear, hash calculations with INSERT, UPDATE and DELETE querys

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your flag is not indexed the database has no choice but to scan every row and check the status. It will make no significant difference which test you apply, so the queries will take the same amount of time.

If you have indexed your flag then the database will decide whether to use the index or do a table scan based on its own statistics about system performance, and what estimate it makes of the number of rows it might select. It will choose what it thinks is the fastest method. The exact query (active or !inactive) might make a difference, but it's unlikely to be significant.

Answer (score 0):

This will depend on the exact database engine and more heavily on the indexing (and type of indexes) you choose.

For instance, if a bitmap index is available it may give more or less performance depending on the spread of data etc.